# Ruby: How do I parse links with Nokogiri with content/text all the same?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, web-scraping, nokogiri

What I am trying to do:  Parse links from website (http://nytm.org/made-in-nyc) that all have the exact same content. "(hiring)"     Then I will write to a file 'jobs.html' a list of links.  (If it is a violation to publish these websites I will quickly take down the direct URL.  I thought it might be useful as a reference to what I am trying to do. First time posting on stack)

DOM Structure:

```
<article>
<ol>
<li><a href="http://www.waywire.com" target="_self" class="vt-p">#waywire</a></li>
<li><a href="http://1800Postcards.com" target="_self" class="vt-p">1800Postcards.com</a</li>
<li><a href="http://www.adafruit.com/" target="_self" class="vt-p">Adafruit Industries</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.adafruit.com/jobs/" target="_self" class="vt-p">(hiring)</a</li>
```

etc...

What I have tried:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def find_jobs
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://nytm.org/made-in-nyc'))
   hire_links = doc.css("a").select{|link| link.text == "(hiring)"}
   results = hire_links.each{|link| puts link['href']}

 begin
   file = File.open("./jobs.html", "w")
   file.write("#{results}") 
 rescue IOError => e
 ensure
   file.close unless file == nil
 end

puts hire_links
end

find_jobs
```

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/glonsberry/c81b59265c6c32948d32#file-scraper)

Example Result:
`[344] #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcfa2e2276c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcfa2e226e0 name="href" value="http://www.zocdoc.com/careers">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcfa2e2267c name="target" value="_blank">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcfa2e1ff1c "(hiring)">]>`

So it successfully writes these entries into the jobs.html file but it is in XML format?  Not sure how to target just the value and create a link from that.  Not sure where to go from here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how `results` is defined. `results` is an array of Nokogiri::XML::Element:

```
results = hire_links.each{|link| puts link['href']}
p results.class
#=> Array
p results.first.class
#=> Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

When you go to write the Nokogiri::XML::Element to the file, you get the results of inspecting it:

```
puts results.first.inspect
#=> "#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x15b9694 name="a" attributes=...."
```

Given that you want the href attribute of each link, you should collect that in the results instead:

```
results = hire_links.map{ |link| link['href'] }
```

Assuming you want each href/link displayed as a line in the file, you can join the array:

```
File.write('./jobs.html', results.join("\n"))
```

The modified script:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def find_jobs
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://nytm.org/made-in-nyc'))
  hire_links = doc.css("a").select { |link| link.text == "(hiring)"}
  results = hire_links.map { |link| link['href'] }       
  File.write('./jobs.html', results.join("\n"))
end

find_jobs
#=> produces a jobs.html with:
#=> http://www.20x200.com/jobs/
#=> http://www.8coupons.com/home/jobs
#=> http://jobs.about.com/index.html   
#=> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Mechanize. It leverages Nokogiri, and you can do something like

```
require 'mechanize'

browser = Mechanize.new
page = browser.get('http://nytm.org/made-in-nyc')
links = page.links_with(text: /(hiring)/)
```

Then you will have an array of link objects that you can get whatever info you want. You can also use the `link.click` method that Mechanize provides.

Comment: If the OP is only scraping a single page, and there are no forms to fill or buttons to push, then Mechanize is overkill. While it's great when processing a site, it is very heavyweight when doing one page.